# Where do I find the distance measure at k-means?

Tags: python, time-series, k-means

I saw an article at towardsdatascience about using kmeans on timeseries. Link: https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-electricity-profiles-with-k-means-42d6d0644d00
Now I have tried to use it on my own dataset and it works quiet good.
I have daily profiles, it looks like this:
[image] 
My Question is: What ist the distance measure between the daily profiles?
So how its calculating the difference between the daily profiles?
I'm using the following code for the k-means function:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
cluster_found = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
cluster_found_sr = pd.Series(cluster_found, name='cluster')
df_pivot = df_pivot.set_index(cluster_found_sr, append=True )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(18,10))
color_list = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow', 'black', 'white']
cluster_values = sorted(df_pivot.index.get_level_values('cluster').unique())
""
for cluster, color in zip(cluster_values, color_list):
    df_pivot.xs(cluster, level=1).T.plot(
        ax=ax, legend=False, alpha=0.01, color=color, label = f'Cluster {cluster}'
        )
    df_pivot.xs(cluster, level=1).median().plot(
        ax=ax, color=color, alpha=0.9, ls='--'
    )

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0 , 24))
ax.set_ylabel('watt')
ax.set_xlabel('hour')
```

before I use a method which helps me to decide how many clusters i should pick.

```
sillhoute_scores = []
n_cluster_list = np.arange(2,31).astype(int)

X = df_pivot.values.copy()

sc = MinMaxScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

for n_cluster in n_cluster_list:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_cluster)
    cluster_found = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
    sillhoute_scores.append(silhouette_score(X, kmeans.labels_))
```

Comment: Are you asking what distance measure could you use? More specifically what distance measures would be meaningful on clusters with different k?

Comment: I only copied it and used it for my data and just don't understand on which basis the given algorith decide how to differ the daily profiles. (so which distance measure it uses)

Comment: Kmeans typically uses an L2 distance (or Euclidean distance). Take a look at the [KMeans wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). After you understand how KMeans works, it may clear things up.

Comment: Actually I already read how kmeans works, my problem is to understand how it works on time series. Like does it first calculate the averege of every daily profile and then it goes on with the calculation of the distance?

Comment: From looking at the article, it looks like he is just using every hour as a feature. So he has a 24 feature vector. Then kmeans will use Euclidean distance in on that feature